# Adjusting rule lengths in fncychap with [Rejne] option

Tags: fncychap

I am using the fncychap package, option Rejne, which sets a box chapter title. I just want to reduce the size of the created box? Does there exist any way to do this?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\geometry{left=4cm, right=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=4cm}
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\kant[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is all hard-code in `fncychap.sty`, the lines after `\DeclareOption{Rejne}`. I see no other way than copying the whole thing into your preamble, and make the modifications there (within `\makeatletter/\makeatother`)

Comment: by the way there is a bug in `fncychap` (Ah no this is a bug of the `Bjornstrup` style, not the `Rejne` style sorry.) as it does `\setlength{\mylen}{\textwidth}` at a too early time.